# Test Oracle stored procedure with cursor as INPUT in SQL developer

Tags: oracle, input, cursor

Can someone guide me on how to test/execute a stored procedure in Oracle SQL developer with cursor getting passed as INPUT?

```
PROCEDURE TEST_PROC
  (
    TestCursor   IN sys_refcursor,
    return_code  OUT VARCHAR2
  );
```

The plan is to loop through the cursor and insert rows in some table. I want to test this using SQL developer Execute option.

Comment: Why not create another procedure that creates your cursor and calls this procedure?  From SQLDeveloper call proc TEST_DRIVER which instantiates cursor and calls TEST_PROC?

Comment: well, there is a node application that will call this procedure. I am not even sure if the node application can even pass a cursor type object.